SWIG how to opt out whole interface and wrap just one function
Lets assume that I got class A looking like that:
class A {
public:
 A() = default;
 ~A() = default;

 void foo();
 void bar();
 void baz();
 void qux();
};


I want to create wrapper of that class, but I just need to use function foo.
I know that I can use
%ignore A::bar;
%ignore A::baz;
%ignore A::qux;

to avoid wrapping rest of the functions, but it take a look writing and If someone will add new function he'll have to add new ignore.
Is there in SWIG options to opt out whole interface of class and just tell which function I want to wrap ?

Dont spam tags. This is not Java.

IIRC SWIG will only export what you define in the interface file, you don't need to explicitly ignore anything. If you don't want to wrap a function, don't add it in the interface file and it should do the work. That being said my memories are very vague so I may be wrong.

Of course I don't need to add them to the interface, but I need them in that interface in other cases, just don't need them in case of wrapping it to java by SWIG, that's way I'm asking about opt out option.

Don’t %include the whole header file for the class in the swig .i file. Just enter manually the parts of the class to wrap.

@MarkTolonen how to input them manually ? You mean with %rename or how ?

Type the parts of the header to wrap instead of including the header

Look at this:
https://github.com/mmomtchev/magickwand.js/blob/05a84af7f11164ad947528743947d4dc650f77f2/src/MagickCore.i#L6
In your case:
%rename("$ignore", regextarget=1, fullname=1) "^A::.+";
%rename("%s", regextarget=1) "foo$";


SWIG only wraps what you tell it to, so in the interface(.i) file, use something like:
%module test

%{
#include "A.h"    // Needed to build the wrapper
%}

// Only declare what you want to wrap instead of %include the whole header.
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
    void foo();
};

Now if other functions are added to the include file, they won't be wrapped.
